# Ordenar localizaciones de mas cercana a lejana node desde mi posición

Tags: javascript, java, sql, typescript, mongodb

Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación pero necesito saber de todos los elementos de la base de datos sea mongo o sea SQL o la que sea, saber cuales son de todos lo elementos dada una posición sea una calle o coordenadas, cuales son los que están mas cerca de mi en ese momento.
la cosa, existe alguna forma de hacer la consulta a la la base de datos y que esta ya te devuelva esos datos ordenador para paginar lo o se tendría que hacer una consulta, traer todos los objetos y volcar lo  en otra lista ya ordenada para después solicitarlo paginado?
Gracias es simplemente una duda.

se que en Android existe el método `distanceTo` existe algo en javascript que sea igual??

Un ejemplo es walapod tu entras y te salen primero los 20 primeros artículos ordenados por cercanía.

Si consulto desde Madrid y me salen  los items ordenados de mas cerca a mas lejos.

Si consulto desde Barcelona y me salen los items ordenados de mas cerca a mas lejos
teniendo esta colección

```
 {
    "_id": "5ee74a38c3ba249508a8c014",
    "index": 0,
    "name": "bici 1",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -36.167271,
    "longitude": 30.045611
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a3822b1e1b8dfbb86bc",
    "index": 1,
    "name": "bici 2",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 88.416006,
    "longitude": -49.909889
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38f5a372da4f52bba1",
    "index": 2,
    "name": "46189e93-74f8-4c1a-9fac-9ed1e4228175",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 83.427032,
    "longitude": 2.615932
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38f9e7f101da8a8df0",
    "index": 3,
    "name": "bici 3",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -16.717524,
    "longitude": 38.962426
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38dc519af5f867fe8e",
    "index": 4,
    "name": "bici 4,
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -7.242124,
    "longitude": 96.967712
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38089ab586ae9219cb",
    "index": 5,
    "name": "bici 5",
    "isActive": false,
    "latitude": -2.478039,
    "longitude": 15.451835
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a384052a686fa06b845",
    "index": 6,
    "name": "bici 6",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 23.08468,
    "longitude": -109.18014
  }
```

Teniendo esa colección, la pregunta es ??

Hay alguna forma de solicitar los datos por cercanía ??

Tendría que primero transformar los datos de las coordenadas y crear una nueva colección con la distancia hasta mi posición y hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin crear una nueva colección con la distancia.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es nada clara. Quieres consultar tu base de datos (cualquier base de datos, por lo que dices en tu pregunta, ya eso es muy amplio), la consulta es: *¿cuáles son los que están mas cerca?* ¿Acaso hablas de Geolocalización? ¿Coordenadas? ¿Están más cerca de qué? ¿Más cerca entre ellos? ¿Más cerca de un lugar? ¿Más cerca de Dios? Podrías poner un ejemplo del tipo de dato, y lo que pretendes hacer? Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: creia que se entenderia mejor, cualquier base de datos si, lo pongo me es igual que sea relacionar o no, esta escrito, creia que tambien se entendía de que eran posiciones "coordenadas de algo" se un movil o una posición antes dada y que era desde mi o desde un punto que yo de, no creo que sea importante desde que desde una posición ordenar varias posiciones o " coordenadas"

Comment: Claro que ahora se entiende que necesitas, pero tu pregunta sigue siendo muy abierta. Lo que tu quieres es realizar una consulta de geolocalización. En MongoDB eso puede ser sencillo si los datos están almacenados para ese propósito. En una base de datos relacional la cosa está en construir la consulta SQL adecuada de acuerdo a cómo almacenes tus datos. No hay una respuesta única. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Saludos

Comment: Buenas Mauricio para en la programación hay disintas formas de hacer las cosas, la pregunta la pregunta es cual seria la mas adecuada, dices que en mongo si están almacenados para ese propósito "almacenado hay unas coordenadas" de cada articulo ponte que consulto los artículos en madrid y luego en barcelona para que aparezcan ordenados por cercanía, se tendrían que volver en otra colección con la distancia o habría otra forma sin tener que volcar los datos? no se si me comprendes ?

Comment: Te comprendo perfectamente. Pero si no muestras algo específico lo que yo o cualquiera te  responda será adivinando cosas. Y no es la idea del sitio. Aquí no escribimos tutoriales ni damos opiniones sobre cuál cosa es mejor o peor. Aquí respondemos preguntas a problemas específicos. Por ejemplo: *tengo este documento de Mongo con esta estructura, hago esta consulta y me devuelve eate resultado, pero yo necesito este otro, ¿en qué estoy fallando? ¿qué me falta?*. Puedes leer [ask] y [mcve]. No lo tomes a mal, es sólo una recomendación para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: la pregunta creo que es explicada mauricio, es que si hay alguna forma de consultar los datos sin tener que crear otra coleecion o modificar la que esta añadiendo la distancia, si no la entiende lo siento pero creo la pregunta es bastante explicita 
de unos datos A,B,C,D,E,F;G,X,Y... que cada uno tiene una coodenada desde mi movil "celular" cuando consulto esos datos que me aparezcan ordenador por cercania, entonces hay alguno mentodo coo en android que existe el distanceTo que te da la distancia entre un punto y otro, y si se pueden traer ordenados
No se si conoces aplicaciones como walapod

Comment: Ahora si, ya voté ppr reabrir. No sólo es mi voto, sino el de otro usuarios. Habrá que esperar o si deseas la via expresa, elimina esta pregunta y vuelve a formularla con los datos que has aportado. Saludos